# Display photos taken in different image views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have two image views. When I click a button (e.g. takePhoto) underneath of the 1st image view, the photo taken appears in the first image view. However, when I tap the second "takephotoTwo" button, I want the second photo taken to appear in the second image view (imageTwo). Right now, if I take a photo using the second "takephotoTwo" button, the final (same) image appears in both image views. See code below - does anyone know how I can fix this? I hope I explained this well enough.

**E.g.**

> The photo taken with takePhoto (button) should appear in imageView, and the photo taken with takephotoTwo (button) should appear in imageTwo.

**ViewController.m**

```
  - (IBAction)selectPhoto:(id)sender {

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

    - (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }


    - (IBAction)takePhotoTwo:(id)sender {

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }

    - (IBAction)selectPhotoTwo:(id)sender {

        UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        picker.delegate = self;
        picker.allowsEditing = YES;
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

        [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];

    }


    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

       UIImage *secondImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
       self.imageTwo.image = secondImage;

        UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
        self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

        [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];


    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is easily achieved by keeping track of which button was tapped or storing a reference to the proper image view based on which button was tapped. Then in the image picker delegate method you set the appropriate image view.

Add an instance variable of type `UIImageView *` named `selectedImageView`.

Then update the rest of your code as follows:

```
- (IBAction)selectPhoto:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    selectedImageView = self.imageView; // Add this

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    selectedImageView = self.imageView; // Add this

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)takePhotoTwo:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    selectedImageView = self.imageTwo; // Add this

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (IBAction)selectPhotoTwo:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    selectedImageView = self.imageTwo; // Add this

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    selectedImageView.image = image;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Thank you!! :) Works like a charm.

Comment: PS - any idea why this question would've been down voted ?! It seemed like a legitimate Q to me...

Comment: Not happy - and now I can't ask questions anymore -__- ARGH!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that no matter which button is tapped, you are giving your UIImagePickerController the same `delegate`. Therefore the same `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` is called. But at that point you have no way of knowing which button was tapped, so you have no way of knowing what image view to put the picture into.

Either give the UIImagePickerController a different `delegate` for each different button, or store in an instance variable somewhere some information about which button was tapped, so that `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` can decide correctly what to do.